# Ansible installation on Eks cluster

Tags: ansible, amazon-eks

i've createa an eks cluster using terraform, and now i want to deploy this ansible role in the cluster
https://github.com/githubixx/ansible-role-traefik-kubernetes.

Unfortunatley, when running the command ansible-playbook i get this error message
`status:Failure, message:forbidden: User system:anonymous cannot get path /apis`
when the role tries to check if the namespace exists. If i run the same command using kubectl i correctly get an answer.

Comment: this means apis folder cannot be accessed or doesnt exit

Comment: Assuming that the failure is in the "[Ensure namespace](https://github.com/githubixx/ansible-role-traefik-kubernetes/blob/master/tasks/prerequisites.yml#L2)" task, that error message suggests that the `k8s` module simply isn't authenticating.  Can you tell us more about your environment? Are you using the default kubeconfig file, or are you setting the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable? Does `kubectl config current-context` report something that looks correct?

Comment: Yes @larsks, the error is in Ensure namespace task. I'm using the default kubeconfig file ( at path /Users/tiziano/.kube/config ), also the output of current-context seems correct to me kubectl config current-context
arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:5xxxxxxxxxx/cluster/company-production

Comment: That all seems fine. I'm out of ideas, sorry!